# Why can’t I fully uninstall Grabit?

Tags: uninstall

I uninstalled Grabit last month, but occasionally I found some Grabit files on my disc C! I tried to uninstall it again but found no Grabit files on Windows Add/Remove Programs. Why can’t I fully uninstall it?

Answer (score 1):

Applications when installed on Windows:
- they put their files in their folder. i.e. C:\Program Files\Grabit
- they put *.dll files in windows directory
- they put values & keys in windows registry ( accessed by regedit)
- they might put files in common windows directories.

I found the better way that another good application could collect all those related information & remove them all when you want to uninstall.

This excellent application (for me) is revouninstaller.
It is available to download for free on http://www.revouninstaller.com/

It is very easy to use.

Hope this will get your issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the software, but some apps leave a lot of trash in system after uninstall. In some cases this is because the author wants to prevent you from repeated trial version installation but I hate when the software leaves such hidden fragments in my system. I often have to use tools like Revo Uninstaller, some tools are also in Piriform Ccleaner and in more difficult cases I also had to use RegClean or Regseeker to remove these fragments from system.

Answer (score 0):

RevoUninstaller works pretty well.

Some programs create a list of their files to help the uninstall process and yet do not update the list when their files are updated either through program updates or other changes. This is one common cause of partial uninstalls. Others assume you'll be reinstalling the app, and so leave their config files to "make it easier" for you.

I have gotten used to going into Program Files and deleting program directories after uninstall. Also check the following locations for files:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\
C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\
C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\

These tend to be the most common places for programs to leave files.

Regarding the registry, don't modify it yourself unless you know what you're doing. Use Piriform CCleaner to remove extraneous and unused registry entries.